# How can I add an array within multiple arrays?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I created a large array that is similar to this:

```
data = [ [1,2,3], [0,1,3],[1,5,3]]
```

How can I make it so my new array sums up each individual array as shown?

```
data = [ [6],[4],[9] ]
```

Comment: How would you handle `[[[1, 2], 3], [4,5]]`, for instance? More importantly, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are good for this:

```
[[sum(x)] for x in data] # [[6], [4], [9]]
```

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
>   applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
>   some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
>   iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
>   certain condition.

You're wanting to make a new list where each element is the result of some operations (a [**sum**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) in this case) applied to each member of another sequence or iterable (your list of lists).

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
a = [ [1,2,3], [0,1,3],[1,5,3]]
b = []

for i in a:
  sum = 0
  for j in i:
    sum+=j
  b.append([sum])
print(b)
```